# SQL Server CREATE ASSEMBLY

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I use command :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [xxxx] from 'my dll path ' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

but I get an error :

> system.web, version=4.0.0.0 not found

Why do I need a .net framework dll? I don't understand.

The sql server has install .net framework .

Comment: `CREATE ASSEMBLY` creates a database object to hold a **.NET** assembly - therefore you do need the SQL Server built-in .NET framework, of course. But that SQL CLR does **not** include the `System.Web` assembly which contains mostly web-forms based GUI controls - nothing you'll need in SQL Server code, really. But as the error states - the assembly you're trying to get into SQL Server obviously *does* reference that `System.Web` dependency - get rid of it and you should be fine

Comment: Thank you , it’s clear to me now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server's internal CLR host (i.e. SQLCLR) is a highly restricted environment. It is not like using the OS's CLR host (i.e. console apps and Windows / desktop apps, which are what most programmers are used to), and is closer to creating a web app where there are shared resources and no use for things such as UI functionality. There is a short list of libraries that are included in SQL Server's CLR: [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries). Other .NET Framework libraries, such as `System.Web`, would need to be loaded manually, if they can be loaded at all. It is generally best to avoid such things as you can easily get into trouble when doing so. For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read content on that site): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).

In your case, if you need to connect to a web page or web service, you are better off using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` as they are included in the supported libraries and only require `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` and not `UNSAFE`.